# Constexpr is not allowed in declaration of friend template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, constexpr

I'm porting a C++14-`constexpr` codebase from Clang to the latest g++-5.1. Consider the following reduced code snippet of a home-grown `bitset` class that has been compiling correctly since the halcyon days of Clang 3.3 (almost 2 years now!)

```
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t>
class bitset;

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr bool operator==(const bitset<N>& lhs, const bitset<N>& rhs) noexcept;

template<std::size_t N>
class bitset
{
    friend constexpr bool operator== <>(const bitset<N>&, const bitset<N>&) noexcept;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- error from this piece
};

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr bool operator==(const bitset<N>& /* lhs */, const bitset<N>& /* rhs */) noexcept
{
    return true;
}

int main() {}
```

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/EVdayJ5tzkp0Y9v7) on Wandbox. However, g++-5.1 and the current trunk release give an error:

> 'constexpr' is not allowed in declaration of friend template
>   specialization

**Question**: is this a known g++ bug or is Clang not conforming to the latest Standard?

**Note**: the above only uses C++11 style `constexpr` features, since there are no modifications taking place inside `operator==`, so it seems some weird interference between templates, friends and constexpr.

**UPDATE**: filed as [bug 65977](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65977) on Bugzilla.

Comment: And 4.8.2 complains about [an extraneous `inline` specifier](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ZNUj29hUVVn5RgJr)...

Comment: I don't see any obvious answers to this, it may be helpful to open a gcc bug report, especially since their is implementation difference between clang and gcc. I don't see any defects that relates to this and although Marco's answer is perhaps correct, it is not obviously correct to me.

Comment: I personally would have left the bounty in place so the answer could have received more upvotes. It is a perfect answer and deserves more than 2 votes.

Comment: That was probably the best 50 rep I have spent :-)

Comment: TIL you were first recipient of the constexpr tag bronze badge, so I understand why you consider it rep well spent (as I for my rep).

Comment: I spend enough time at the edges of the language that these types of awesome answers are invaluable.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**GCC is wrong here.**

All references are to N4431, the latest C++ WD.

[tl;dr: There's a difference between a function being *inline* (or more precisely, being an *inline function*, as defined in 7.1.2/2) and being declared with the `inline` specifier. The `constexpr` specifier makes a function inline, but isn't an `inline` specifier.]

Specifiers are described in subclause 7.1 of the C++ standard, and are an element of the grammar. Therefore, whenever standard talks about a `foo` specifier appearing somewhere, it means that specifier literally appeared within the (parse tree of the) source code. The `inline` specifier is a *function-specifier*, described in subclause 7.1.2, and its effect is to make a function be an inline function. (7.1.2)/2:

> A function declaration (8.3.5, 9.3, 11.3) with an `inline` specifier declares an *inline function*.

There are two other ways to declare an inline function, without using an `inline` specifier. One is described in (7.1.2)/3:

> A function defined within a class definition is an inline function.

The other is described in (7.1.5)/1:

> constexpr functions and constexpr constructors are implicitly
>   inline (7.1.2).

Neither of these says that the behavior is as if an `inline` *specifier* were present, merely that the function is an inline function.

**So why does this rule exist?**

There's a simpler form of this rule in (7.1.2)/3:

> If the `inline` specifier is used in a friend declaration, that declaration shall be a definition or the function shall have previously been declared inline.

The purpose of this is to allow friend declarations to be ignored in most cases -- they are not permitted to add "new information" to the befriended entity, except in the special case where they are defining a friend function. (This in turn allows an implementation to delay parsing a class definition until it's "needed".) Thus we also see, in (8.3.6)/4:

> If a friend declaration specifies a default argument expression, that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the function or function template in the translation unit.

And the same applies to a declaration of a friend specialization of a function template: if it could add extra information, then implementations could not delay parsing the class definition.

Now, note that this rationale does *not* apply to `constexpr`: if the `constexpr` specifier appears on any declaration of a function, it must appear on *every* declaration, per (7.1.5)/1. Since there is no "new information" here, there is no need for a restriction.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks! I'll file a gcc bug report (3 actually, since library DR 2275 and 2301, concerning constexpr tuple functionality, have also not yet been implemented in libstdc++)