# Declaring a constexpr specialization as friend

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, constexpr

I have a templated class `A` and a templated function `f` which returns `A` objects. I want `f<T>` to be a friend of `A<T>` and still be `constexpr`

```
template <typename T>
class A;

template <typename T>
constexpr A<T> f();

//f<T> is a friend of A<T>

template <typename T>
class A {
  friend /* constexpr? */ A f<T>();
  constexpr A() {}
};

template <typename T>
constexpr A<T> f() { return {}; }

int main() {
  constexpr auto a  = f<void>();
}
```

I can't get clang and gcc to agree on what's right here.  If I don't put `constexpr` in the friend declaration, gcc works fine but clang won't compile it, erroring with:

```
main.cpp:18:18: error: constexpr variable 'a' must be initialized by a constant expression
  constexpr auto a  = f<void>();
                 ^    ~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:18:23: note: non-constexpr function 'f<void>' cannot be used in a constant expression
  constexpr auto a  = f<void>();
                      ^
main.cpp:9:12: note: declared here
  friend A f<T>();
```

If I mark it as `constexpr` in the friend declaration, clang compiles fine but gcc gives me the error:

```
main.cpp:9:27: error: 'constexpr' is not allowed in declaration of friend template specialization 'A<T> f<T>()'
   friend constexpr A f<T>();
```

How can I make everyone happy?

Comment: see [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29871138/constexpr-is-not-allowed-in-declaration-of-friend-template-specialization) for a similar bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int main() { constexpr auto a  = f<void>(); }
```

This specializes the function template `f` as the function `f<void>()`; during the specialization of `f`, the compiler also attempts to instantiate `A<void>`, which in turn declares the specialization `friend f<void>()`.

These two declarations **must** match for `constexpr`:

[dcl.constexpr] / 1

> [...] If any declaration of a function or function template has a `constexpr` specifier, then all its declarations shall contain the `constexpr` specifier. [*Note:* An explicit specialization can differ from the template declaration with respect to the `constexpr` specifier. —*end note*]

Clang should probably be erroring out earlier when you omit `constexpr` in the `friend` declaration rather than stamping out what appears to be a non-`constexpr` function, but at least it accepts the correct syntax.

Gcc shouldn't allow the version missing `constexpr`, and gives an error when you do provide `constexpr` due to a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65977). This has since been fixed in the trunk and I can confirm it works now, although it still does not provide an error when `constexpr` is missing.